# Component not getting displayed

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a component inside app.component angular.
But my inner component is not displayed.
Here is the app.component code

```
<app-buttons></app-buttons>
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buttons',
  templateUrl: './buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buttons.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Buttons component HTML :

```
<h1> This is Buttons Component</h1>
```

In HTML :
**Hello World** is displayed (since it is written in App.component.html)
but
"**This is Buttons Component**" is not displayed

Please help

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you add your component to your `AppModule`?

Comment: Yes, If you see, App-buttons is added in app.component.html

Comment: there are no errors in Terminal as well as Browser console

Comment: Yes, it is already addedin app.modules "import { ButtonsComponent } from './buttons/buttons.component';"

and also added in declarations

Comment: Try to restart `npm start` or `ng serve` and then refresh your browser.